# Progressbar in listbox?

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2008, listbox, progress-bar

I have a listbox that contains a bunch of file downloads, i want to add a progress bar to the current download to let the user know the progress of the download.
I cannot figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use owner drawn list box

Use a normal ListBox and set DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed and handle the two events MeasureItem and DrawItem.

The downside is that you have to take care of all the drawing yourself, but at least text and a progress bar are easy to draw.

Answer (score 0):

Why ListBox? Use ListView, with a simple Google you find ton of ListView+Progress Bars.